# NSString:sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode Android equivalent

Tags: android, textview

Basically, what I would like to do is for a given text (String), with a given width and font mesaure the text height. I would then use the obtained height to create a TextView with the specified height and width. I've tried to measure the text height using methods from the Paint class, but they only give me approximate results. What would be the best way to achieve this?
In the iPhone sdk, this can be easily done by using the `NSString:sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode` function. Is there anything similar in the Android sdk?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: there is no simple solution. I've managed to get some workaround that roughly gives me what I wanted to do